# Twitter API call limit - per token or per IP?

Tags: api, authentication, twitter, access-token

I am developing a feature that display the recent 5 tweets for a particular tweeter user. I am using the application-only authentication and get the bearer token to query the tweeter API.

I saw there is a limit on the numbers of request to Twitter API in every 15 mins.
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits

```
                                        user auth        app auth
GET statuses/user_timeline  statuses    180              300
```

My question is the limit is per bearer token or per IP?
For example, If

1. User A and user B are using the same token, query the same user's timeline(Eg, Yahoo), would the limit will be 300/2 for each user in every 15 mins?
2. User A and user B are using the same token, query the different user's timeline(Eg, One for Google, One for Yahoo), would the limit will be 300/2 for each user in every 15 mins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, it will be divided by 2. It is recommended to use User authentication to user credentials for such case.
2. The rate limits are on the endpoint. So if you do 5 requests that start with `statuses/user_timeline  statuses` only 295 request will remain.

I am not sure if you know c# but you can check this quite easily with the Twitter library `Tweetinvi` as followed:

```
var remainingBefore = RateLimit.GetCurrentCredentialsRateLimits().StatusesUserTimelineLimit.Remaining;
var tweets = Timeline.GetUserTimeline(userId);
var remainingAfter = RateLimit.GetCurrentCredentialsRateLimits().StatusesUserTimelineLimit.Remaining;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Our feature doesn't want user to get login. So user authentication will not applicable in our case.

In the second point, is that mean if there are 300 user using the same token to request statuses/user_timeline  statuses. So the limitation will be reached immediately and then these 300 user will not able to request statuses/user_timeline  statuses in this 15 mins time period?

Comment: You are correct. Another way people usually do to circumvent the problem is to create multiple tokens that they use in turn. But you will need to create user tokens with your own accounts if you do not want the users to authenticate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The user tokens you mean is that the Access Token in the Twitter app settings --- Keys and Access Tokens? If that is the case,  I can only apply one Access Tokens. I wonder what is the difference between this Access Token and the Bearer Token?

Comment: When I speak of UserToken I do mean the AccessToken and AccessTokenSecret. I usually mention them as user token as they are a unique token between a user and an app. You can have multiple "AccessTokens" if you have multiple accounts authorizing your app via the Twitter REST API. The `BearerToken` acts differently as it is unique to your app. If you have all the info you need please set the question as answered.

Comment: Hey there @Linvi, sorry for digging in a very old thread. I have a use case where I want to get one user's timeline, every few seconds (or minutes maybe). I'm wondering what rate limits do I need to care about? [The docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/rate-limits) mention something about `900 per user` and `1500 per auth`. I'm not completely sure what that means. I have a project and a standalone application too in my dashboard. How should I go about this? Any help is appreciated?